# Extending AsyncTask without overriding its paramters

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, extends

As i found in *AsyncTask* class the declaration of this class is as follows

```
public abstract class AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

When i extend AsyncTask i should override those parameters (i.e.. AsyncTask), I don't need that, i need to add some functionalities to AsyncTask but still able to override those parameters when extending my CustomAsyncTask, such that i need to make my custom AsyncTask declaration like this also

```
public abstract class CustomAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

But when i do that the "Params, Progress, Result" are not recognized as in AsyncTask class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that i can declare my custom class like this

```
public abstract class CustomAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
public abstract class CustomAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
      extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extend to `AsyncTask` with out `overriding` the `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute` but you have to `override` `doInBackground`.

```
public class AsyncTaskParseJSONData extends AsyncTask {
   public AsyncTaskParseJSONData(JSONObject response) {
        this.responseObject = response;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    }
}
```

See if this helps you.